# Format time display only date in php

Tags: php, magento

I want to display only date from the below function.

```
$this->formatTime($item->getCreatedTime(), 'short', true);
```

This displays both date and time of creation something like:

> 3/21/2017 11:42 AM

I want only 3/21/2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime($item->getCreatedTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$date = $this->formatTime($item->getCreatedTime(), 'short', true);

$newdate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date));

echo $newdate; // Output : 3/21/2017
```

Comment: This will be exactly what you want .

Answer (score 0):

You can use date format

```
 echo date('m/d/Y', $this->formatTime($item->getCreatedTime(), 'short', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers by other users are not correct, using date will not take Magento's time zone configuration into account.

Instead following should be used:

`Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('m/d/Y', $item->getCreatedTime());`

Comment: Yes, however using PHP's `date` function will lead to inaccurate dates due to Magento's timezone settings. This is why using Magento's `core/date` model should be used instead. :)